# I have email address. I dont want to show full information. So I am thinking mask some character using Regex or MaskFormatter

Tags: java, regex, string

Input and desired result

1) testing@mint.com - t***g@m***.**m

I want to do this by using regex or mask.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
public class MobileMasking { 
       public static void main(String[] args) { 
          String email = "danish3jawed@gmail.com";
          String masked = email.replaceAll("(?<=.).(?=[^@]*?.@)", "*"); 
          System.out.println(masked); 
       }
}
```

When I use

```
String email = "testing@mint.com"; 
String masked = email.replaceAll("(?<=.).(?=[^@]*?.@)", "");
```

The output is coming like `t*g@mint.com` but i want like this `tg@m***.**m`.

Comment: Please share what you have come up with so far.

Comment: String email = "testing@mint.com";
String masked = email.replaceAll("(?<=.).(?=[^@]*?.@)", "*"); output is coming like this t***g@mint.com but i want like this t***g@m***.**m

Comment: So, you are using Java, not JavaScript? Please update the question with these details.

Comment: can u help Mr Stribizhev?

Comment: yes i am using java not javascript !!

Comment: package com.infotech;

public class MobileMasking 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  String email = "danish3jawed@gmail.com";
  String masked = email.replaceAll("(?<=.).(?=[^@]*?.@)", "*");
  
  System.out.println(masked); 
 }}

Comment: What if input is `foo.bar@mint.co.uk`

Comment: If `foo.bar@mint.co.uk` should not be supported, you could try [`(?<!^|@)[^@.](?!$)(?![@.])|(?<!^)\G.(?![@.])(?!$)`](https://regex101.com/r/nL1aA4/4) and replace with `*`. If you need to support the one with dits, you can use [`^(.)([^@])*@(.)(([^@])*)([.]([^.])+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/nL1aA4/3) and replace with `$1***$2@$3***$5.**$7`.

Comment: hi anubhava, we dont require .co.uk , we only require .com...plz help regarding this

Comment: @Danish: Please check my 2 suggestions and let me know what exactly you need.

Comment: mr  stribizhev,  it format is fine but the length of string is not corretct...can you look into this ??  $1***$2@$3***$5.**$7

Comment: Aha, that means you provided an incorrect expected result in your question.

Comment: @stribizhev,  String email = "danish3jawed@gmail.com";   output should be : d*****d@g***.**m

Comment: @stribizhev, LENGTH should be same after formatting also.

Comment: I would use [this code](http://ideone.com/7YzWdF), please check if it works for you.

Comment: Please review my edit, I just moved all your comments to the question. I think what you write is not what you mean to say. Please edit so that the question is clear.

Comment: thanks for effort @stribizhev, but befote dot it should be * but it is coming with value... i will look into this ...u also look if possible ...thanx !!

Comment: Like this - http://ideone.com/PgaUSC?

Comment: @stribizhev thanks now its exact format. !! thanks once again !!

Comment: Since anubhava's suggestion is shorter, I'd rather refrain from posting my solution. If you find mine nice and more readable, I will.

Comment: @stribizhev ...yes anubhava suggestion is shorter...but thanx for your effort also !! anubhava thanx to u too !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this lookaround based regex:

```
email = email.replaceAll("(?<!^|@)[^.@](?!@|$)", "*");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hO1lF1/1)

RegEx Breakup:

```
(?<!^|@)  # previous char is not start OR @
[^.@]     # current char is not a DOT or @
(?!@|$)   # next char is not line end OR @
```

Comment: @anubhava...yes it is !! thanx !!

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/rH3wC6/2

Explained:

```
(?<=^.|@.) # match the start or a @, followed by any non-newline character
(?<toreplace>[^@]*?) # match anything except @
(?=.@|.$) # match any character followed by the end of the string or a @
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/PeRvy1

Wait, do you need to keep the dots in the second part? Isn't it useless?

Comment: yes i understand...but what should i do ...it is not my requirement, it is our client requirement !!

Comment: Well, I think it's obvious that an email *does always have* a dot in the second part. Otherwise it's just not a valid email.